# What is the function of the two segnos in this score?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, musical-forms, repeats

What is the function of the two segnos in the following score?

At the start of measure 7 there is a segno, and in measure 70 there is a second segno together with a Da Capo. In the following measure there is this indication (in Spanish):

> *Se toca otra vez la primera parte y luego la tercera*

Which translates as:

> "The first part is played again and then the third one"

[image: Score of "Teresita - Valse"]
(see [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EjN20nnXGzrgLUFGaxVaDpIBbuH1O34g) for larger image)

Comment: Interesting; this looks like an error in notation of some kind. Do you by any chance have a recording of this piece?

Comment: No, this piece never has been recorded, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

This piece seems to have several mistakes in instructions and in notation.  "The first part is played again and then the third one" doesn't seem to make sense.  It's too vague.  Also, the D.C. should be a D.S. al Fine. That makes more sense of the two segnos.  There should logically be a Fine half way along the 5th line, the bar before the repeat.  In this way, the format makes more logical sense - play the page from beginning to end, then do the repeat from half way through the 5th line, until the D.S. al Fine (beginning of second to bottom line), then from the sign (b.7) and finish half way through line 5.

In notation, b.16 right hand should, I think, be the same as in b.32.  Also, b.20 left hand should be the same as in b.19, and finally the 'B' in the left hand of the first bar in the final line should be a 'C'.

That's my interpretation of what may have been meant in this little piece, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Jomiddnz is probably correct, but here's a possible alternative.  Play thru to the end, then to the repeat to the end, then back to the repeat a third time, but this time hit the DS (written DC) and then finish off at the double bar in third desk. That might explain what the editor was thinking so far as "third time" goes.